# NS2 NAM output for SMAC protocol for 2 nodes not showing CBR transmission

Tags: networking, tcl, protocols, simulator, ns2

I am trying to simulate SMAC protocol using ns2.34. I have specified the routing protocol as AODV and smac syncflag is set to 1 with the initial energy of 50000 J. The JOURNAL_PAPER code has not been activated and no modifications have been done in the cpp modules of ns2. 
The network structure consists of 2 nodes only wherein node 0 is the udp agent node and node 1 is null agent node. CBR is attached to the udp agent. Both nodes are within the range of each other. All nam trace, agent trace, route trace and mac trace are ON.
No error is generated during execution of tcl file but the NAM output does not show any CBR transmission which has been attached to node 0. Kindly suggest changes required in ns2.34 for activating the NAM trace output in the animator.

Following is the TCL Script for the above simulation:

```
set opt(chan)        Channel/WirelessChannel
set opt(prop)        Propagation/TwoRayGround
set opt(netif)       Phy/WirelessPhy
set opt(mac)         Mac/SMAC                   ;# MAC type
set opt(ifq)         Queue/DropTail/PriQueue
set opt(ll)          LL
set opt(ant)         Antenna/OmniAntenna

set opt(x)        800    ;# X dimension of the topography
set opt(y)        800        ;# Y dimension of the topography
set opt(cp)        "/root/ns-allinone-2.34/ns-2.34/tcl/mobility/scene/cbr-50-10-4-512"
set opt(sc)        "/root/ns-allinone-2.34/ns-2.34/tcl/mobility/scene/scen-670x670-50-600-20-0"
set opt(ifqlen)        50        ;# max packet in ifq
set opt(nn)        2        ;# number of nodes
set opt(seed)        0.0
set opt(stop)        700.0        ;# simulation time
set opt(tr)        Test.tr    ;# trace file
set opt(nam)       Test.nam    ;# animation file
set opt(rp)             AODV           ;# routing protocol script
set opt(lm)             "off"           ;# log movement
set opt(agent)          Agent/DSDV
set opt(energymodel)    EnergyModel     ;
#set opt(energymodel)    RadioModel     ;
set opt(radiomodel)        RadioModel     ;
set opt(initialenergy)  1000            ;# Initial energy in Joules
#set opt(logenergy)      "on"           ;# log energy every 150 seconds


Mac/SMAC set syncFlag_ 1

Mac/SMAC set dutyCycle_ 10

set ns_        [new Simulator]
set topo    [new Topography]
set tracefd    [open $opt(tr) w]
set namtrace    [open $opt(nam) w]
set prop    [new $opt(prop)]

$topo load_flatgrid $opt(x) $opt(y)
ns-random 1.0
$ns_ trace-all $tracefd
$ns_ namtrace-all-wireless $namtrace 500 500

#
# Create god
#
create-god $opt(nn)


#global node setting

$ns_ node-config -adhocRouting $opt(rp) \
         -llType $opt(ll) \
         -macType $opt(mac) \
         -ifqType $opt(ifq) \
         -ifqLen $opt(ifqlen) \
         -antType $opt(ant) \
         -propType $opt(prop) \
         -phyType $opt(netif) \
         -channelType $opt(chan) \
         -topoInstance $topo \
         -agentTrace ON \
         -routerTrace ON \
         -macTrace ON \
         -energyModel $opt(energymodel) \
         -idlePower 1.0 \
         -rxPower 1.0 \
         -txPower 1.0 \
         -sleepPower 0.001 \
         -transitionPower 0.2 \
         -transitionTime 0.005 \
         -initialEnergy $opt(initialenergy)



    $ns_ set WirelessNewTrace_ ON

    for {set i 0} {$i < $opt(nn) } {incr i} {
        set node_($i) [$ns_ node]    
        $node_($i) random-motion 0        ;# disable random motion

    }

set god_ [God instance]
$node_(0) set X_ 250.159448320886
$node_(0) set Y_ 320.107989080168
$node_(0) set Z_ 0.000000000000
$node_(1) set X_ 360.514473960930
$node_(1) set Y_ 400.755796386780
$node_(1) set Z_ 0.000000000000

for {set i 0} {$i < $opt(nn) } {incr i} {
    $ns_ initial_node_pos $node_($i) 30+i*100
}

set udp_(0) [new Agent/UDP]
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(0) $udp_(0)
set null_(0) [new Agent/Null]
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(1) $null_(0)
set cbr_(0) [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
$cbr_(0) set packetSize_ 512
$cbr_(0) set interval_ 10.0
$cbr_(0) set random_ 1
$cbr_(0) set maxpkts_ 50000
$cbr_(0) attach-agent $udp_(0)
$ns_ connect $udp_(0) $null_(0)



$ns_ at 1.00 "$cbr_(0) start"
#$ns_ at 177.000 "$node_(0) set ifqLen"


#
# Tell all the nodes when the simulation ends
#
for {set i 0} {$i < $opt(nn) } {incr i} {
    $ns_ at $opt(stop) "$node_($i) reset";
}
$ns_ at $opt(stop) "puts \"NS EXITING...\" ; $ns_ halt"

puts "Starting Simulation..."
$ns_ run
```

Comment: Can you post your tcl script here?

Comment: Added script above .. kindly check and revert as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

You have not created animator file anywhere that stores the animation information. you need to define a finish procedure that is called at last. It should be similar to :

```
proc finish {} {
global ns tracefd namtrace
$ns flush-trace
close $tracefd 
close $namtrace
exec nam Test.nam &
exit 0
}
```

Comment: I call the nam output separately using nam command in terminal based on the nam file created here. Can there be any issue in creation of nam file here ?

Comment: set namtrace    [open $opt(nam) w]  $ns_ namtrace-all-wireless $namtrace 500 500  this is syntax for creating nam file, which gets created after execution of this ns file.  Any issue in the above syntax ?